# Can you tell me what this RBloomberg formula means?

Tags: statistics, r, bloomberg, indicator, moving-average

I've been asked to re-create a spreadsheet that used RBloomberg using a different data source. But I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what one of the spreadsheet's formulas does. Can anyone tell me what exactly the following formula is calculating?

I think it's something along the lines of (CurrentPrice/30dayEMA-1)*100. But I can't seem to get that calculation to match the values given by this formula. I wonder if this is caused by differences in things like whether this formula is using adjusted prices or not, when the EMA calculation starts, etc.

Thanks!

=IF($A19<>"",(BDH($A19,"PX_LAST",$B$7,$B$7,"Days=A", "Fill=P", "Dts=H")/BTH($A19,"EMAVG",$B$7,$B$7,"EMAVG","TAPeriod=30","DSClose=PX_LAST","Dir=V","Dts=H","Sort=A","QtTyp=P","Days=T","Per=cd","UseDPDF=N", "CshAdjNormal=Y","CshAdjAbnormal=Y","CapChg=Y")-1)*100,"")

(A19 is a security name.B7 is the current date.)

Comment: Yes it looks like it - have you taken the overrides into account? ("CshAdjNormal=Y","CshAdjAbnormal=Y","CapChg=Y")

Comment: What do the overrides do?

Comment: They affect the way corporate actions are taken into account (splits, dividends etc.).

Comment: I've tried using adjusted prices (like Yahoo's) and unadjusted prices. I believe this should account for dividends, splits, and the like. Neither option seems to work.

Comment: You should ask HELP HELP on your terminal.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have Bloomberg myself. I am re-creating a spreadsheet for someone who does.